# Custom `conditions` in `belongsTo` not working

Tags: cakephp

**BACKGROUND**

I am using CakePHP 2.4

I have 3 tables

Table `terms`

```
CREATE TABLE `terms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vocabulary_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `presentation` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Table `vocabularies`

```
CREATE TABLE `vocabularies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `presentation` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Table `patients`

```
CREATE TABLE `patients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `patient_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

**EXPECTED**

In the `Patient` model I'd like to have a `belongsTo` relationship to `Term` with custom conditions.

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'PatientType' => array(
        'className' => 'Term',
        'foreignKey' => 'patient_type_id',
        'conditions' => array('PatientType.vocabulary_id' => 1)
    )
);
```

**CURRENT**

The `conditions` is not working, instead of having only rows with `vocabulary_id = 1`, I have all the rows in table `terms`.

Comment: I use to debug query generated by cake by placing query to session in file 'lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php' function name :execute

Comment: I have done that. The `conditions` is not in the generated query.

Comment: upto this points there is nothing wrong on your code And it must work.. So, problem is somewhere else.. I would like to see your controller...

Comment: In the controller I tried to do `$this->Patient->PatientType->find('list')`. I expect to have data from table `terms` which has `vocabulary_id = 1`